# Class attribute change listener with Spring

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I would like to know if anyone has experience with setting up a bean in spring with an interceptor that automatically fires an event when a property is changed.

```
public class DTO {
    public String a;    
}

public class Listener() {
    public void objectChanged(Object ob) {
        System.out.println("Object changed");
    }
}
```

Regarding to the classes over, if I do the following.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DTO ob = AppContext.getBean(DTO.class);
    ob.a = "new value";
}
```

What I want to happen here is that the listener objectChanged function is fired automatically by spring when property a is changed on the DTO object. Where do I go to find information about this? and is it possible?

Comment: What about using setter/getter methods?

Comment: Getter and setters are ok, but that requires that I add one line of code for each setter, like "objectIsDirty". I was hoping for something more elegant ;)

Comment: You need to get into the habit of using get/set accessors. It's a bad habit to access property directly at its variable. Eclipse has automated way of propagating the get/set accessors given a range of variables.

Answer (score 0):

As @DaDaDom asks, why do you want to avoid getters/setters? I don't think your idea is possible, but it could be done using AOP in a manner similar to

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="yourcut" expression="execution(* your.dto.package.*.set*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="attribChangedAdvice" pointcut-ref="yourcut" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="attribChangedAdvice" class="your.package.YourListener">
    ...
</bean>
```

You could then have the listener place the changed object in queue for insertion/update to the DB. Backing the queue with a map of sorts, you could even optimize by replacing twice-modified objects before they get inserted.

Cheers,

Comment: To clarify, this is data objects that are stored in a document database. So my idea was that this objects could automatically be saved to database when they are changed. They are supposed to be identically in memory as they are stored in the mongodb database.

today they are stored by manually invoking the saveObjectToDatabase. Was hoping to make this 100% automagically. :)

Comment: Interesting problem and approach. Still, I think aspect programming might work, but it very much depends on how many transactions you're expecting; it could easily break under load due to a high amount of class proxies.